# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'

Tags: python

I got an error,ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test2'.I made test1.py and test2.py.I wanna call test2.py's module in test1.py.So I wrote codes `import test2 as test` in test1.py but the error happens.I rewrote `from test2 import test` but same error happens.What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?I am using IDE so I think I can install module automatically, but in this time it cannot be done.

Comment: Are both the files at the same location? check it first. If not, use the same folder for both the files and then  use import test2 as test then whatever method you want to call you can call it using test.method_name inside test1.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong....

```
from test2 import test
```

means from the test2 module import a function or variable named test...
The actual syntax is `import test2`...In that case make sure that the two python files are in the same directory.....

Comment: thank you for your answer.I wrote your codes `import test2`,but error happens NameError: name 'test2' is not defined .test1.py and test2.py are in same directory.What is wrong in my codes?

Comment: It has to work...I am pretty sure that you have some name problem..Make sure you named it correctly...that {test2.py} does not contain any spaces or other characters....